# What is the difference between Bitmap and Drawable in Android?

Tags: android, android-drawable, terminology, android-bitmap

I googled but i couldn't find any article to describe about the difference between Bitmap and Drawable in Android.

Comment: This solution should be able to answer your questions: [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5877202/813207)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

A Bitmap is a representation of a bitmap image (something like java.awt.Image). A Drawable is an abstraction of "something that can be drawn". It could be a Bitmap (wrapped up as a `BitmapDrawable`), but it could also be a solid color, a collection of other Drawable objects, or any number of other structures.

Most of the Android UI framework likes to work with Drawable objects, not Bitmap objects. A View can accept any Drawable as a background. An ImageView can display a foreground Drawable. Images stored as resources are loaded as Drawable objects.

Comment: if a bitmapDrawable wraps a bitmap , what would occur if we call recycle() on the bitmap within it ? also , what does recycle() do for API11 and above?

Comment: @androiddeveloper - I'm not sure, but it won't be anything good. Once a bitmap is wrapped by a BitmapDrawable, the drawable "owns" the bitmap and is supposed to manage its life. If you call `recycle()`, you are interfering with that relationship. At best, the drawable will draw nothing; more likely, some sort of exception will be thrown later on. According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29), `recycle()` with API11+ does the same thing it always did: it allows you to free the native pixels as soon as you know you are done with them.

Comment: they say there that it frees the native memory of the bitmap , but we know that as of API 11 , everything related to the bitmap (including its raw data) is inside the heap , so recycle seems like a weird thing to do ...

Comment: @androiddeveloper - Looking at the [source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java), it seems that there's still a native bitmap. For performance purposes, the raw buffer is exposed as a public member (although still hidden from the public API). Calling `recycle()` will still free the native bitmap; it will also set the member buffer to `null`.

Comment: yes, i've read it too , but it doesn't make sense, since they said on google IO that the bitmap is no longer stored in the native memory . i'm really confused of how could it be.

Answer (score 47):

Bitmap is not an image. Bitmap is a map of bit (note name: Bit-map). And this map represents pixels on which you can draw something. It may be your own custom bitmap (not image), for example square:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

or you can create Bitmap object from image:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.your_image);
```

A Bitmap is a pixels holder. And Canvas is used to draw something on your bitmap (on Bitmap pixels).

Everything about Drawable is well described above.

**TL;DR**

Some people write that you draw on Canvas. You don't draw on Canvas. You draw on Bitmap pixels with Canvas helper method.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawColor(Color.RED) // now all bitmap pixels became red
```

Comment: Nice answer deserves +1 :) Thanks for the explaining by lines of code.

Comment: perfectly explained

Answer (score 40):

Drawable is something which can be drawn. E.g. layout, vector image (line, circle), font, image and so on

Bitmap - is specific type of Drawable which is image, like: PNG, JPEG or so

Comment: A [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) (`android.graphics.Bitmap`) is not a subclass of [Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html) (`android.graphics.drawable.Drawable`).

Comment: Sure, it's my fault. I meant BitmapDrawable

Comment: But they say **Bitmap: the simplest Drawable, a PNG or JPEG image.** in docs.

Comment: I thought I pasted from this link. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Bitmap

Answer (score 17):

**Drawable Resource**

A `Drawable` resource is a general concept for a graphic that can be drawn to the screen and which you can retrieve with APIs such as `getDrawable(int)` or apply to another XML resource with attributes such as `android:drawable` and `android:icon`. There are several different types of drawables:

- *Bitmap File*, A Bitmap graphic file, (.png, .jpg, or .gif), creates a `BitmapDrawable`.
- *Nine-Patch File*, A `PNG` file with stretchable regions to allow image resizing based on content (.9.png), creates a `NinePatchDrawable`.
- *Layer List*, A `Drawable` that manages an array of other `Drawable`s. These are drawn in array order, so the element with the largest index is drawn on top, creates a `LayerDrawable`.
- *State List*, An `XML` file that references different bitmap graphics for different states (for example, to use a different image when a button is pressed), creates a `StateListDrawable`.
- *Level List*, An `XML` file that defines a `Drawable` that manages a number of alternate `Drawable`s, each assigned a maximum numerical value, creates a `LevelListDrawable`.
- *Transition Drawable*, An `XML` file that defines a `Drawable` that can cross-fade between two `Drawable` resources, creates a `TransitionDrawable`.
- *Inset Drawable*, An `XML` file that defines a `Drawable` that insets another `Drawable` by a specified distance. This is useful when a `View` needs a background `Drawble` that is smaller than the View's actual bounds.
- *Clip Drawable*, An `XML` file that defines a `Drawable` that clips another `Drawable` based on this `Drawable`'s current level value, creates a `ClipDrawable`.
- *Scale Drawable*, An `XML` file that defines a `Drawable` that changes the size of another `Drawable` based on its current level value, creates a `ScaleDrawable`.
- *Shape Drawable*, An `XML` file that defines a geometric shape, including colors and gradients, creates a `ShapeDrawable`.

Also see the Animation Resource document for how to create an `AnimationDrawable`.

Note: A color resource can also be used as a `Ddrawable` in `XML`. For example, when creating a `StateListDrawable`, you can reference a color resource for the `android:drawable` attribute (`android:drawable="@color/green"`).

**Bitmap**

A bitmap image. Android supports bitmap files in three formats: .png (preferred), .jpg (acceptable), .gif (discouraged).

You can reference a bitmap file directly, using the filename as the resource ID, or create an alias resource ID in XML.

Note: Bitmap files may be automatically optimized with lossless image compression by the aapt tool during the build process. For example, a true-color PNG that does not require more than 256 colors may be converted to an 8-bit PNG with a color palette. This will result in an image of equal quality but which requires less memory. So be aware that the image binaries placed in this directory can change during the build. If you plan on reading an image as a bit stream in order to convert it to a bitmap, put your images in the `res/raw/` folder instead, where they will not be optimized.