# What's the difference between Bitmap, BitmapDrawable and Drawable?

Tags: android, performance, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I saw this answer: [What is the difference between Bitmap and Drawable in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937036/what-is-the-difference-between-bitmap-and-drawable-in-android)

Can anyone give a practical explanation? When to use? Advantage disadvantage?

Comment: Think of it this way:  JPEG and PNG are two examples of image encodings.  So when you are dealing with images there are two things you want to do: decode an image (turn the stream into pixels) and render the image.  `Bitmap` is all about encoding/decoding/manipulating the pixels.  `Drawable` is all about rendering things onto the screen so you can see them.  `BitmapDrawable` is where it all comes together.

Answer (score 4):

`Bitmap` is just an image as-is. Ideally it would be used to draw pixels on the screen with a `Canvas`, using a `SurfaceView` or something like that.

`Drawable` is a class that describes something that can be drawn on the screen.

`BitmapDrawable` is a subclass from `Drawable`. This means that it's a `Drawable` that wants to draw an image.

Usually android views work with `Drawable` objects, so any subclass of `Drawable` is acceptable, this means that if you want to use a `Bitmap` (raw pixels) on a `View` you need to create a `BitmapDrawable` and pass it to it.

Comment: Can we also convert a `Btmap` to `Drawable` and pass it to the view as background?