# Bitmap vs ImageView vs Drawable

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable, terminology, android-bitmap

What is the different between them?

where and why we need to convert from one type to another?

Answer (score 1):

For a difference between bitmap and drawable see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876952/drawable-vs-bitmap)

ImageView is something like `img` tag in HTML. It is the View that displays an image.

Answer (score 0):

**Bitmap** actually refers to the Images like png, jpg, etc.

**ImageView** is a view that is used to display an image. You can call

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(your_bitmap) // displays your bitmap 
imageView.setImageDrawable(your_drawable) // displays your drawable
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_drawable_file) // displays drawable from resource
imageView.setImageURI(Uri_here) // displays from Uri
```

**Drawable** is something that can be drawn like layout, vector, image, etc.