# bitmap size exceeds VM budget vs using drawables android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, drawable

In my app I am fetching 4-5 bitmaps from url and I use them like a gallery.

if i switch images more than 6-10 times I am getting this error:

```
09-01 12:08:45.217: E/AndroidRuntime(350): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
09-01 12:08:45.217: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
09-01 12:08:45.217: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:459)
09-01 12:08:45.217: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:515)
```

This is my code:

```
try {
                            bitmapResult = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url[newPage+1]).getContent());
                          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        v.setImageBitmap(bitmapResult);
```

My question os this:

Will this happen only in emulator?

Morevoer, and more important. Will it me more efficient if using drawable insted? In that case I will convert my bitmap to drawable with code below and I will setImageresource. Do I have to "release" anything?

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmapResult);
```

Comment: a `BitmapDrawable` is just wrapping a `Bitmap` so it uses the same amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

when you are loading bitmaps from you internal storage - recycle the bitmap afterwards!

there are many threads around here with the problem VM out of memory...

Comment: and what about the bitmap vs drawable?

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876952/drawable-vs-bitmap) a thread which answers this question