# Android Bitmap or BitmapDrawable?

Tags: android

I have been programming an android game for some time and I wonder if there is a difference between
a `Bitmap` and a `BitmapDrawable`.

Any answers should include any differences between the RAM, loading speed, etc.

Comment: Maybe it's not clear to you that this is **not** a tutorial site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawable vs. Bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876952/drawable-vs-bitmap)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Bitmap** is **faster to draw** and usually good for background images. There is a significant change to FPS depending on if you draw a bitmap or drawable. Bitmaps are faster to move.Low usage of RAM

You can use **Bitmap drawable**  if you need to do the things like **scaling, moving** and other kinds of **manipulations of the image**. **Not as fast** but there's no other option if you want to do any of those things just mentioned. There is a high usage of RAM in this case.

Side Note : A Drawable that wraps a bitmap and can be tiled, stretched, or aligned. You can create a Bitmap Drawable from a file path, an input stream, through XML inflation, or from a Bitmap object.

Comment: If this answer is acceptable to you mark it as accept.

Comment: I'm a litte bit confused you say Bitmaps are faster to move but when i want to move it i shoud take a Drawable.. Do you mean it is dependent how many objects i want to draw or reather to move? What shoud now i take for moving objects(max. 25)?

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap is something that only represents an image or graphic. But on the other hand, BitmapDrawable is something that can be drawn like vector, layout,image etc.